# Failed to add collection:', [Error: ensureNotFalsy() is falsy] - React native

Tags: database, collections, rxdb

I'm working on react native project where method is written in react and I want to save the collection. I'm using SQLite rxdb plugin to save it but getting this error everytime. even I tried with lokiJS plugin but no success.